# Hotel Soap API Error = Premature end of file

Tags: xml, soap, sabre

I have created  a soap request for hotels but keep getting an error when testing. I am new to coding & stackoverflow so please highlight if I have missed anything.

Here is the error followed by my php code;

```
<soap-env:Envelope><soap-env:Header/><soap-env:Body><soap-env:Fault><faultcode>soap-env:Client.InvalidEbXmlMessage</faultcode><faultstring>Unable to create envelope from given source: Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file.</faultstring><detail><StackTrace>javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create envelope from given source: Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file.</StackTrace></detail></soap-env:Fault></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

The Code I am using:

```
<?php
//sws-crt.cert.sabre.com // https://sws3-sts.cert.sabre.com
//Data, connection, auth
$soapUrl = "https://sws-crt.cert.sabre.com"; // asmx URL of WSDL
//?op=OTA_HotelAvail
// xml post structure

$xml_post_string = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-    ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                  <wsse:Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" env:mustUnderstand="1">
                   <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                    <wsse:Username>xxx</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password>xxx</wsse:Password>
                   </wsse:UsernameToken>
                  </wsse:Security>
                  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
                <SOAP-ENV:Body>
           <OTA_HotelAvailRQ Version="2.1.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<AvailRequestSegment>
<Customer>
  <Corporate>
    <ID>ABC123</ID>
  </Corporate>
</Customer>
<GuestCounts Count="2"/>
<HotelSearchCriteria>
  <Criterion>
    <HotelRef HotelCityCode="HNL"/>
  </Criterion>
</HotelSearchCriteria>
<TimeSpan End="06-28" Start="06-20"/>
</AvailRequestSegment>
</OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
          </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';   // data from the form, e.g. some ID number

$headers = array(
"Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
"Accept: text/xml",
"Authorization: Bearer Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3547302473499669854!495515!0!!E2E-1 X-Originating-Ip: xxxxxx ",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Pragma: no-cache",
"SOAPAction: OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ",
"Content-length: " . strlen($xml_post_string)
); //SOAPAction: your op URL

$url = $soapUrl;

// PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "powderwhite:B=Antika789"); // username   and password - declared at the top of the doc
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

header('Content-type: text/xml');
// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
// converting
/// $response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
// $response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);
// convertingc to XML
//   $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
// user $parser to get your data out of XML response and to display it.
//echo $parser;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are Sabre SOAP APIs that you are looking to consume, you need to pass as part of the SOAP Header the Session Token that was created and returned from the SessionCreateRQ service. Session is not passed on the header. Example is posted below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <m:MessageHeader xmlns:m="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <m:From>
                <m:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">99999</m:PartyId>
            </m:From>
            <m:To>
                <m:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</m:PartyId>
            </m:To>
            <m:CPAId>ABC</m:CPAId>
            <m:ConversationId>abc123</m:ConversationId>
            <m:Service m:type="OTA"/>
            <m:Action>OTA_HotelAvailLLSRQ</m:Action>
            <m:MessageData>
                <m:MessageId>mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com</m:MessageId>
                <m:Timestamp>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</m:Timestamp>
                <m:TimeToLive>2001-02-15T11:15:12Z</m:TimeToLive>
            </m:MessageData>
            <m:DuplicateElimination/>
            <m:Description>Hotel Request</m:Description>
        </m:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" valueType="String">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESF!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-3552340994681278428!1838077!0!1!E2E-1</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <OTA_HotelAvailRQ Version="2.1.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AvailRequestSegment>
                <Customer>
                    <Corporate>
                        <ID>ABC123</ID>
                    </Corporate>
                </Customer>
                <GuestCounts Count="2"/>
                <HotelSearchCriteria NumProperties="50">
                    <Criterion>
                        <HotelRef HotelCityCode="DFW" HotelName="HYATT"/>
                    </Criterion>
                </HotelSearchCriteria>
                <TimeSpan End="06-28" Start="06-20"/>
            </AvailRequestSegment>
        </OTA_HotelAvailRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```